# IEEEtran BibTeX Style - how to deactivate URLs?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, links, ieeetran

I am using the following BibTeX style for my bibliography.

```
   \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
   \bibliography{IEEEabrv,references,thesis}
```

This formats bibliography entries like this:

[image]

, including a hyperlink to the web if provided. For brevity, I don't want it to show the URLs. How can I deactivate them?

EDIT: Let me clarify - I want to save space by not showing the URL, although the BibTeX entry for the publication contains a URL.

Comment: Do you want to deactivate the hyperlinks for all possible URLs in your document or just for those URLs appearing in your bibliography?

Comment: I want to remove the URLs from my Bibliography without editing the .bib file.

Comment: I think the only way to do this would be editing the IEEEtrans.cls and make it somehow ignore the URL entries. Can you edit the .cls?

Comment: I've just goggled it a bit, and apparently you can do this by editing the .bst file. Check this out http://www.tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2007-August/014582.html

Comment: @Dan Yes, this works. Had you posted this as an answer, I could accept it now. ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you don't want BibTeX to print out the URL field for a given entry even though a URL field is present, you need to edit the bibliography style file -- in the present case, the file `IEEEtran.bst` -- to disable this printing. Make a copy of the file `IEEEtran.bst` and call it, say, `myIEEEtran.bst`. Open the new file in a text editor and search for the function `format.url`. It should look like this:

```
FUNCTION {format.url}
{ url empty$
    { "" }
    { this.to.prev.status
      this.status.std
      cap.yes 'status.cap :=
      name.url.prefix " " *
      "\url{" * url * "}" *
      punct.no 'this.status.punct :=
      punct.period 'prev.status.punct :=
      space.normal 'this.status.space :=
      space.normal 'prev.status.space :=
      quote.no 'this.status.quote :=
    }
  if$
}
```

Replace this function with the following "dummy" function:

```
FUNCTION {format.url}
{ url empty$
    { "" }
    { "" }
  if$
}
```

In short, you're telling BibTeX not to print out *any* information contained in the URL field. Save the file, update the filename database if necessary (e.g., if using TeXLive, type `texhash` in a command window), and be sure to use the new bibliography style file from now on. Happy TeXing!

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer, as the author of this question recognised in my comment above (which is pretty much the same as this answer) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57087/ieeetran-bibtex-style-how-to-deactivate-urls#comment119802_57087

Comment: This also worked with a bib style called `aipproc.bst`

Comment: @drevicko - Thanks! Indeed, the method should work for a great many (all?!) bibliography styles that feature a function called `format.url` and, naturally, .bib files with entries with a field named `url`.

Answer (score 14):

The IEEEtran BibTeX style provides an option to deactivate the display of URLs through use of its BST control functionality. To do so, create a BibTeX entry in one of your .bib files as follows:

```
@IEEEtranBSTCTL{BSTcontrol,
CTLuse_url = "no",
}
```

Then, activate the BST control with the `\bstctlcite` command. It is best to place this command right after `\begin{document}` because it will only alter the formatting of the citations that follow it.

```
\begin{document}
\bstctlcite{BSTcontrol}
```

This method is described in the [IEEEtran BibTeX how-to file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf).

Note that this method avoids editing the ieeetran.bst style file.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little bit late to the party, but for anyone else looking for a way to do this it is also possible to make a new version of the `IEEEtran.bst` file as above and edit the following lines:

```
% #0 turns off the display of urls
% #1 enables
FUNCTION {default.is.use.url} { #1 }
```

to be:

```
FUNCTION {default.is.use.url} { #0 }
```

Make sure you **rename** the file and use the **edited** version.

Answer (score 0):

`\hypersetup{hidelinks=true}` will make the links "hidden" (typeset without emphasis, but still clickable).

You can switch this on and off for parts of the text (using `\hypersetup{hidelinks=false}` appropriately), so you can hide only the bibliography links or all links in the document.

Comment: inserting this command gives me an error: Package kvsetkeys Error: Undefined key 'hidelinks'.

Comment: It is also not a solution to my problem, because it removes the colored border/clickable link, not the URL. I hope have formulated the question more clearly now.