# Bibtex Entering extended mode and hangs

Tags: bibtex

When I compile/typset test.bib file, this appears:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9)
**entering extended mode**
```

Then the program hangs. What to do? Thank you in advance

edit: right now the reference does appear in main document when compiled. However, when I change bibliography style in the line`\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}`, the reference still appears in the same style as before. I tried IEEEtran, plain and unsrtnat. Shouldn't they give different style in the document? Mainly, I don't want the url to appear in main doc.

Main document Latex code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\section{A}

Yesyesyes \cite{muiva}

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

`test.bib` code:

```
@article{muiva,
    title = {Effect of doping concentration on the properties of aluminium doped zinc oxide thin films prepared by spray pyrolysis for transparent electrode applications},
    volume = {37},
    issn = {0272-8842},
    url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0272884210003986},
    doi = {10.1016/j.ceramint.2010.09.042},
    pages = {555--560},
    number = {2},
    journaltitle = {Ceramics International},
    author = {Muiva, C. M. and Sathiaraj, T. S. and Maabong, K.},
    urldate = {2014-10-18},
    date = {2011-03},
    keywords = {A: Thin films, D: {ZnO}, Spray pyrolysis},
}
```

Comment: You can not compile `bib` files.

Comment: But you have to run it somehow right? Like click on the green button with small triangle inside

Comment: You have to run `bibtex` using some menu or button on your editor. After that, compile the `tex` file again.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: If you change the bibliography style you have to rerun `bibtex`.

Comment: The trouble with saying `%The usual preamble` is that there is no such thing.

Comment: Sorry, just edited the code to be more accurate

Comment: For a posting that discusses how to suppress the contents of the URL field, see [IEEEtran BibTeX Style - how to deactivate URLs?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57087/5001) The answer given there applies to the IEEEtran bibliography style,. However, it should be obvious how to adapt it to other bibliography styles that feature a function called `format.url`.

Answer (score 1):

Do *not* run BibTeX on the `.bib` file. Instead, assuming your main tex file is called `mytexfile.tex`, you should run the following sequence of commands:

```
pdflatex mytexfile
bibtex mytexfile
pdflatex mytexfile
pdflatex mytexfile
```

Observe that no file name extensions are prodived. Of course, if you use either xelatex or lualatex rather than pdflatex, you should adjust the command name given on lines 1, 3, and 4 above accordingly. Depending on the front-end editing program you may be using, there may be a button to click on that will automatically issue this sequence of commands.

With some suitable modifications (such as loading the packages `natbib` and `url`, and changing the `date` field type to `year`), your MWE produces the following output if latex, bibtex, latex, and latex are run:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@article{muiva,
    title = {Effect of doping concentration on the properties of aluminium doped zinc oxide thin films prepared by spray pyrolysis for transparent electrode applications},
    volume = {37},
    issn = {0272-8842},
    url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0272884210003986},
    doi = {10.1016/j.ceramint.2010.09.042},
    pages = {555--560},
    number = {2},
    journaltitle = {Ceramics International},
    author = {Muiva, C. M. and Sathiaraj, T. S. and Maabong, K.},
    urldate = {2014-10-18},
    year = 2011,
    keywords = {A: Thin films, D: {ZnO}, Spray pyrolysis},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\usepackage[obeyspaces,hyphens]{url}

\begin{document}
\section{A}
Yesyesyes \cite{muiva}

\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: probably a very noob question but...

I'm using latex on windows. I always just click on the green button with triangle inside it. So where/how to type and run these commands you've mentioned above?

pdflatex 
mytexfile
bibtex mytexfile
pdflatex mytexfile
pdflatex mytexfile

Comment: @Wait - which front-end program do you use? There are quite a few programs that feature a "green button with triangle inside"...

Comment: oops  it's Texworks. >.<

Comment: @Wait - Next to the green circular button with the triangle inside, there's a bar that (probably) says "pdfLaTeX". Click on that bar and you'll get other programs to choose from. Select "BibTeX", and then click on the green circular button to, you guessed it, run BibTeX. The select "pdfLaTeX" again and run that program twice more. Please, please, make an effort to learn the features of the front-end program.