# TeXstudio do not produce the pdf file of my text

Tags: pdftex, texstudio

I started to write my thesis yesterday in TeXstudio, everything was good until now when I can not view my pdf on the right side of the code, and also there is not anymore the pdf file in my latex folder. Can you help me, please?

I have 2 errors showing up,
One is for missing `{` and `}` and the other is undefined control sequence both are at the rows I used \end{split}.
When I compile other files, I can view the pdf form of them also the pdf files on the folder.
I did not make any changes in the settings of TeXstudio. It was working normally until 1 time I clicked the double-arrow and showed up as in the photo.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't comment because I lack reputation, I want to answer this way.

First and foremost it would be interesting to see what the error message in the lower right says. Probably it already helps. Since the question lacks information we can only guess the solution.

(I hope you recompiled and clicked the "double-arrow" button, but i guess so).

Another question i have, is whether or not it just stopped compiling or didn't it compile all the time? You can look up possible errors by checking the logs. Also it would be interesting to know what you did 'just before' everything went wrong.
(Maybe changed some settings you weren't so sure about, added some package or command, ....)

Well from now on its just debugging, or adding some information to your problem.

Comment: I am writing mathematical proofs and so I am using \begin{split}. I had 4 errors, but two of them I figured out just now. The first error says that } {are missing and the second error says that there is an undefined control sequence \end{split}. Maybe since I ignored these 4 errors for a time it stopped. I just clicked the double-arrow button it stopped showing the pdf form and when I looked at my folder I couldn`t find the pdf file of this code. When I open other files and compile them I can see the pdf form. I am sorry for my amateur explanation, I am very new in using latex and thank you.

Comment: Is it working now? If not you could add some Details and I'd take another look. 
Most often it helps to just go some steps backwards and see when the error happens.

Comment: Well, I did make some mistakes while using { and now I have found it. Now there is no error but the log file shows this:                                                                         
  **This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 2.9.7380 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.4.11)  16 JUN 2020 00:02
entering extended mode!**

Comment: This too, **Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 2807 strings out of 480930
 40287 string characters out of 2896007
 283968 words of memory out of 3000000
 18683 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 534345 words of font info for 33 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 37i,20n,31p,268b,165s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!**

Comment: Well I can't help much with the second error message as I would guess theres still some error somewhere in your code. Most often it helps to comment out large sections and try to get some running version and then add back some commented parts to see when it breaks down. 

As far as the first log message goes i'd try updating your TeX Distribution. Maybe some other question from this site helps you -> [see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208545/bibtex-entering-extended-mode-and-hangs)

Comment: I found the problem. I mixed some curly brackets while using this sign | which in probability is a condition sign and in latex as I see we write another way. I was really confused because at the beginning I just wrote `|`in this way and it showed up good.