# Why the issue number is missing in reference?

Tags: citing

My source is:

```
@article{Astrm2014,
 doi = {10.1016/j.automatica.2013.10.012},
url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.automatica.2013.10.012},
year  = {2014},
month = {jan},
publisher = {Elsevier {BV}},
volume = {50},
number = {1},
pages = {3--43},
author = {Karl J. A{\r{}}str\"{o}m and P.R. Kumar},
title = {Control: A perspective},
journal = {Automatica}
}
```

use package:

```
\usepackage{cite}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
```

However, my reference output is:

[image]

why the issues `number` of the reference is missing?

Comment: Because IEEE chose not to include it? It's not a mandatory field. Btw, your `\r{A}` seems corrupted, maybe `{\AA}str\"{o}m` would work better?

Comment: Thanks, `{\r{A}}str\"{o}m` goes the same way, your way is simpler. In fact, in all published IEEE paper, `no.` is included.

Comment: Then we need a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) I'm afraid.

Comment: It's okay, I will do it immediately, wait for me a while.

Comment: Did you try with `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}`, which is the official style from IEEE?

Comment: @yo' The following answers is more quick than  the MWE I'm preparing.

Comment: @egreg You're right, it's confirmed from this link [http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/bibtex/]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ieeetr` bibliography style is set *not* to typeset the contents of the `number` field of an entry of type `@article`.

As @yo' has already pointed out, you also need to fix the spelling of the first author's surname. I suggest you use `{\AA}str{\"o}m`. For more on how to input accented characters in bibliographies, see the posting [How to write “ä” and other umlauts and accented letters in bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57743/5001)

While you're fixing up the entry, you should also change the value of the `month` field from `{jan}` to `jan`. What's the difference, you may ask? The latter is recognized by BibTeX as a predefined *string variable* that evaluates to "Jan.", whereas the former will just be rendered as the *string constant* "jan".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{abcxyz.bib}
@article{Astrm2014,
  doi = {10.1016/j.automatica.2013.10.012},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.automatica.2013.10.012},
  year  = {2014},
  month = jan,
  publisher = {Elsevier},
  volume = {50},
  number = {1},
  pages = {3--43},
  author = {Karl J. {\AA}str{\"o}m and P. R. Kumar},
  title = {Control: A perspective},
  journal = {Automatica}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{cite}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{abcxyz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: plus your other answer (see: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57098/44227])  solved this problem perfectly

Answer (score 4):

The official bib style from IEEE is called `IEEEtran.bst`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Astrm2014,
  doi = {10.1016/j.automatica.2013.10.012},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.automatica.2013.10.012},
  year  = {2014},
  month = jan,
  publisher = {Elsevier {BV}},
  volume = {50},
  number = {1},
  pages = {3-43},
  author = {Karl J. {\AA}str\"{o}m and P. R. Kumar},
  title = {Control: {A} perspective},
  journal = {Automatica},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\cite{Astrm2014}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Note that I used `filecontents*` just to make the example self contained, use your own bib file. Note also how I fixed the first author's name and the title. The abbreviation for the month should not go in braces.

[image]

Comment: @Mico It has already been fixed.

Comment: It works perfect. Another question, I want to ignore the `[Online]. Available:......`, how could I do it without delete or comment the `url`?

Comment: @WangyanLi You can't without editing the `.bst` file.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it actually needs edit the `.bst`.  I found this page [http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57098/44227] solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let me make a summary. The efforts from @Mico and @egreg help a lot, much appreciated.

The main reason of `Why the journal number is missing in reference?` is that the `\bibliographystyle` is misused. the `ieeetr` is not an official bibliography style, the official one is  `IEEEtran`, see this page [http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/bibtex/](http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/bibtex/]), this bibliography style can make the reference output with `no.`, just as @egreg posted 
[image]

However, here comes another question, the `url` information is also included in the output, which is not wanted by IEEE reference format. As pointed by @egreg

> You can't without editing the `.bst` file.

Fortunately, @Mico's other answer has provided a solution on how to edit the `.bst` file, see this [https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57098/44227]. With the efforts above, we can finally solve this problem perfectly:

[image]

Hopefully, the other readers may find this useful.